# Gnome 3 panel shrinking application indicators

Tags: gnome, indicator, gnome-panel

today I added a couple of indicators to my gnome-shell panel, like Skype, weather and some sensors. The problem that I'm facing is that indicators that take a considerable amount of space, like the clock (that is showing the time and date) shrank considerably.

I realized that the total amount of space occupied by all these indicators never exceeds 50% of my screen width.

I'd like to avoid this behavior, and allow each indicator to take the space it needs.

Please, see [image]!

Also note how the clock is no longer in the middle, but now it's on the right corner.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?